# XSLT Function to pass a node argument concatenate a string then return element value

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm fairly new to xslt but I searched through the topics to see if there is a match for mine but since I can't really understand most of the language I can't find them useful.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. Basically, I want a custom function that can concatenate a string to a node path and return the element value without a template match.  Maybe you can provide some example of function code that can do that and I can review it.

Basically what I want to do is pass the `</root/AccountDetails/plantype>` node to a function like a `<xsl:value-of select=”testlang(/root/AccountDetails/plantype)”/>`

In the function, it will do the language test and return the element value of the node  (Please note there are a lot of English and French nodes nested in different levels) that why I'm passing the whole path.  I'm limited to XSLT 1.0 and can't change the XML passed

**XML Sample**

```
<root>
<AccountDetails>
    <plantype>RRSP</plantype>
    <plantype_fr>CELI</plantype_fr>
</AccountDetails>
<ClientDetails>
    <salutation>Mr.</salutation>
    <salutation_fr>Monseiur</salutation_fr>
</ClientDetails>
<lang>fr</lang>
</root>
```

**Possible function code**

```
<xsl:function name=”testlang”>
<xsl:param name=”str”/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test=”/root/lang[.=’fr’]>
            <xsl:value-of select=”concat($str,’_fr’)”/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select=”$str”/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: There are no "custom functions" in XSLT 1.0 (unless your processor supports them as an extension). You can use a named template instead. However, I don't see a `lang` attribute anywhere in your input example, so I am not sure how your "possible code" can possibly work. --  Also a *node* is not a *string* - you cannot concatenate the two.

Comment: Please look at this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189708/select-all-matching-nodes-using-xpath-and-xslt-without-additional-templates-or). This might help.